# Is there a way to simulate the 3.5e Factotum in 5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-5e, homebrew, conversion

I would like a homebrew class that has the same magical skill-monkey feel that 3.5e's Factotum had. I ideally would like the class to be made using the DMG custom class creation guidelines, and I would like for any answers to be backed by personal experience's with said custom class.

Specifically, I would like this custom class to draw from the entire Wizard's spell list, but, perhaps, it should haver less spells per day than the Arcane Trickster. I would also like for it to have class abilities that pull from other classes, such as Turning and Sneak Attack. I would also like for the custom class to have an ability to take extra actions if there is any way to balance such for 5e. I would like the class to be able to wear light armor. use shields (except tower shield), and have martial weapon capabilities. Finally, I would like for it to have class abilities that apply bonuses to my character equal to my intelligence modifier.

Comment: Why are close votes still coming in if I may ask?

Comment: Class conversion questions for 5e are being [discussed here on meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5325/1204). It seems at the moment they are contentious subject: some feel they could work well here given they meet certain criteria, some do not. We've only had to deal with two before this one. The close votes are currently for Too Broad, so I suspect the reaction is that there may simply be too many equally correct ways to build the kind of class you're requesting. (Some advice from someone who's voted to close would be very helpful, though, in working out the issues in this case.)

Comment: I flagged it as Too Broad for exactly the reason @doppelgreener speculated: there is no "*the* right answer", nor even a possibility for an answer to be "right" or "wrong" (aside from things that don't address the question at all being wrong), only a myriad of answers that are "good" or "bad" to varying degrees.

Comment: It's possible that our advice for making answerable character build questions could be applicable here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1639/1204

Comment: It sounds like you know most of what you want; asking someone to craft a class to your specifications and playtest it before reporting back seems a bit much. Do you have specific questions stopping you from just doing the hard work yourself?

Comment: Voting as unclear. You never asked a question.

Comment: Could this question not fall under "good subjective"?  Especially since I detailed what a good build would look like? I suppose I could do some field research myself, but I just wanted to see what the experts at RPG.SE have come up with.

Comment: @user3735278 Good subjective/bad subjective isn't the problem, it's that the criteria you've supplied is too broad (you'll get lots of answers, all equally valid, which isn't good for our voting system) and which leaves us doing virtually all the work. [Do read our character build advice](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1641/1204). (You may be asking for a class, but I'm pretty sure that's enough within the category of character building that this advice applies.)